# Find commits filtered by comment in Azure Devops Repos

Tags: azure-devops, commit, azure-repos

As we know, every commit in a repository has a comment:

[image]

Is there a way in Azure Repos to find all commits filtering by comments? For instance:

> Find all commits with comments containing keyword 'sonar'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not available in Azure DevOps web page currently.

###### Workaround：

The following is a PowerShell script that uses Azure DevOps REST API to find the comments containing the keyword you need. I filtered the top 1000 records. You can also refer to the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to filter the records you need.

```
    $Orgname = "Orgname" 
    $projectname="projectname"
    $reponame="reponame"
    $keyword="sonar"
    $PAT = "xxxxx"
    
    $PATGetBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")
    $Authentication = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($PATGetBytes)
    $Headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $Authentication) }
    
    $commits = Invoke-RestMethod  "https://dev.azure.com/$Orgname/$projectname/_apis/git/repositories/$reponame/commits?`$top=1000&api-version=6.0"  -Method 'GET' -Headers $Headers  -ContentType 'application/json'

    foreach($commit in $commits.value)
    {
       if ($commit.comment -match $keyword)
       {
          Write-Output "$($commit.commitId)  $($commit.remoteUrl)  $($commit.comment)"
       }  
    }
```

My test result:

[image]

##### Update：

This is the sample to cross search all projects and repos for given organization. It also filtered the top 1000 records for each repo.

```
$organization = "xxxx"
$PAT = "xxxx"
$keyword="sonar"

$PATGetBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")
$Authentication = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($PATGetBytes)
$Headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $Authentication) }


# get all projects of the organization
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"
$projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method 'GET' -Headers $Headers  -ContentType 'application/json'

foreach($project in $projects.value)
{
    # get all repos of the project
    $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/$($project.id)/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0"
    $repos = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method 'GET' -Headers $Headers  -ContentType 'application/json'

    foreach($repo in $repos.value)
    {
        Write-Output "Project: $($project.name), Repo: $($repo.name)"
        # get the commits of the repo
        $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/$($project.id)/_apis/git/repositories/$($repo.id)/commits?`$top=1000&api-version=6.0"
        $commits = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method 'GET' -Headers $Headers  -ContentType 'application/json'


        foreach($commit in $commits.value)
        {
             if ($commit.comment -match $keyword)
               {
                  Write-Output "Commit: $($commit.commitId), url: $($commit.remoteUrl), comment: $($commit.comment)"
               }  
        }
        Write-Output "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"

    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems interesting, , Could you tell me what is $PAT ?

Comment: Hi @fascynacja, PAT is personal access tokens. You can refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows) for the details.

Comment: Great, Do you also know a solution to cross search all projects and repos for given organisation?

Comment: Hi @fascynacja, I updated the answer with the update. Please check, thanks.

Comment: It works perfectly. Although it is not exactly what I asked in the question (because I wanted to be able to do the search in the portal) I am so delighted with this elegant code that I am accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not available in Azure DevOps. You may use Visual Studio Git History search. There is a feature request for your case: [Search / Filter commit messages](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Search--Filter-commit-messages/365924?sort=votes&q=2022)

Comment: I work with IntelliJIdea so unfortumately this wont help me:(